# Regex capture optional groups by delimiters

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I need to parse a string quote by quote text and **@** author and **#** category delimiters. Author and category come in order, but are optional. Like this:

```
"When in doubt - don’t. @Ben Franklin #decisions"

{'text': 'When in doubt - don’t.', 'author': 'Ben Franklin', 'category': 'decisions'}

"When in doubt - don’t. #decisions"

{'text': 'When in doubt - don’t.', 'category': 'decisions'}

"When in doubt - don’t. @Ben Franklin"

{'text': 'When in doubt - don’t.', 'author': 'Ben Franklin'}
```

It's okay if delimiters and whitespaces stick to captured groups, I can strip them later. My current regex:

```
^(.*?)(@.*)(#.*)$
```

only does the job if both @author and #category are present in the input string. Trying to make latter groups optional messes things up for me:

```
^(.*?)(@.*)?(#.*)?$
```

How do I properly capture them?

Comment: What about `^([^@#]*)(@[^#]*)?(#.*)?$`? See https://regex101.com/r/553G4y/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `@` and `#` only appear at the end of string in front of the author or category, you can use

```py
^([^@#]*)(@[^#]*)?(#.*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/553G4y/1), the pattern matches

- `^` - start of string
- `([^@#]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `#` and `@`
- `(@[^#]*)?` - Group 2 (optional): `@` and then zero or more chars other than `#`
- `(#.*)?` - Group 3 (optional): `#` and then zero or more chars other than `#`
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

I would use *named* groups in this case, as follows

```
import re
text1 = "When in doubt - don’t. @Ben Franklin #decisions"
text2 = "When in doubt - don’t. #decisions"
text3 = "When in doubt - don’t. @Ben Franklin"
pattern = "^(?P<text>.*?)(?P<author>@.*?)?(?P<category>#.*)?$"
m1 = re.match(pattern, text1)
m2 = re.match(pattern, text2)
m3 = re.match(pattern, text3)
for m in [m1,m2,m3]:
    print(m.group('text'), m.group('author'), m.group('category'), sep='---')
```

output

```
When in doubt - dont. ---@Ben Franklin ---#decisions
When in doubt - dont. ---None---#decisions
When in doubt - dont. ---@Ben Franklin---None
```

Note that `None` denotes python's `None` not literal string `"None"`, I used `---` to delimit groups, as 3 x dash never appears in your sample data.